# Invalid Use of Void expression error in lambda expression

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda, signals-slots

I am trying to use lambda expression in Qt while I am using the `connect`  function.
My code is like this:

```
for(int i = propertyToNodeMap.size() -1 ; i >= 0 ; --i)
    {
        connect(&mainDialog,mainDialog.accepted(),[=](){
                ; //sth ....
        });
    }
```

I am using Qt 5.3 and MinGW as compiler on Windows 7.
The error message is :

```
error: invalid use of void expression
         });
          ^
```

Moreover I used the Qt documentation and [here](http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html) as reference to implement this piece of code. 
Regards,

Comment: There is no `foreach` in C++.

Comment: @AntonSavin Qt creator has this option, you can use it for containers, It is one of the framework features. look at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15487

Comment: @AntonSavin http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html

Comment: `mainDialog.accepted()`? Is this a pointer to function (signal)?

Comment: What is the type of `propertyToNodeMap`?

Comment: @vahancho yes it is a QDialog signal.

Comment: @AntonSavin yes :QHash<QString, QSet<QString>> propertyToNodeMap;

Comment: @bahrami307, shouldn't it be `&QDialog::accepted` instead?

Comment: @vahancho I think no, because there are many QDialogs in the Project, and we want just to know whether a specific one is Accepted

Comment: Another wild guess: do you need the command line option "std=c++11"?

Comment: @jhoffman0x yes, I add `CONFIG += c++11`, so I can define QHash<QString, QSet<QString>>, with two consecutive > without space!

Comment: I think vahancho was on to something. The first argument (&mainDialog) is what connects a specific QDialog instance. Maybe try using &QDialog::accepted for the second argument.

Comment: @jhoffman0x I tried that, but I got `cannot call member function .. without object`

Comment: @bahrami307, I doubted what you wrote is `&QDialog::accepted()`, just strip the `()`.

Comment: @* I found the problem! the correct syntax of second argument of the function is like this: `&QDialog::accepted`. I don't know what does it mean but it gets compiled in this way! may be it means a reference to a function. now I have problem to interpret this syntax! but thanks every one!

Comment: @Jamboree Your right, thanks! but why?

Comment: `foreach` in Qt is a macro: to create the simplest example of your problem, expand the macro and make sure the problem still occurs, assuming the clause is required to reproduce your problem.  When asking a question here, "here is my code, why does it not compile" is a poor question: instead, eliminate stuff that doesn't make a difference to your code compiling as much as possible, and post a **complete** yet minimal snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Yakk , I compiled my code as much as I could. The problem was not related to `foreach` and the code is now working well. I have to mention that the question was not related to `foreach` and I make the error part clear.

Comment: You seem to be using `sth` as the lambda body. Perhaps there's "sth" wrong with it. Like, I dunno, return statement is missing.

Answer (score 0):

`connect` expects a pointer to member function:

```
connect(&mainDialog, &DialogClass::accepted, [=](){
    ; //sth ....
});
```

I'm assuming `DialogClass` is the class of which `mainDialog` is an instance.

Comment: I think the second one does not work. because `SIGNAL(...)` is convert `...` to `const char *` I suppose.

Comment: Yes, the `SIGNAL` version won't allow connecting to a lambda, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is neither related to lambda expression, nor `foreach` statement(for one who commented for the question before last edition, it is removed now) or `sth' part.
The correct form of connect is like:

```
connect(&mainDialog,&mainDialog.accepted(),[=](){   // missing '&'
                ; //sth ....
        });
```